# How to reset IIS t7.5 to default settings on a local machine

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

How to reset IIS 7.5 to default settings on a local machine and restore everything (such as the default website, app pools, etc) to how it is after the initial install.

I have some problem on my local websites that are not running anymore. after playing with some settings

Thanks